Primes in other sets?
I've just recently learned of the Gaussian primes and it got me wondering, are there primes in other number systems? Like the adic numbers, other clifford algebras? Are there what you could call equivalents to primes in something like groups or say matrices? What do all the things containing primes have in common?
I know these are lots of questions and are of a very wide variety, but I'm veryu curious and I have no one to ask to...

Primes make sense in ring theory.  Start there I guess.

In an arbitary ring we however rather speak of "prime elements" , "prime numbers" usually refers to the prime elements in $\mathbb Z$ , often the negative prime elements excluded.

As Randall said, the definition of prime elements applies to any structure that is a commutative ring.
